# How to open a pop-up without browser address bar?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there, in 2018, a way to open a small pop-up / browser window without an address bar?

Right now, I am using this:

```
 window.open($(this).attr('href'), "Pop-up", "height=200, width=300, toolbar=0, menubar=0, titlebar=0");
```

It looks quite ugly, though, as it contains the browser's address bar as well.

Is there a better solution?

P.S.: I tried all the [options outlined here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) already. None of them work in 2018.

Comment: I thought(?) browsers now always show the URL bar for security reasons.

Comment: I don't understand why my question has been marked as *duplicate* as the "duplicate" question has been asked **8** (!) years ago. The situation has completely changed since then.

Comment: What is wrong with these people that marked it as duplicate. The answer cited is 8 years old.